# VSCode create TypeScript extension to inject global definitions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Assume that I have a TypeScript definition file (`.d.ts`) that defines a namespace `Foo`. I would like to be able to use autocompletion features of `Foo` globally for any TypeScript files, without specially importing, referencing the definition file with comments, or using `tsconfig.json` and Node based support (aka no `node_modules`).

It is more or less like the scenario of defining `window.Foo = ...` somewhere else in the browser and use here in this script.

I am hoping to create an extension that basically injects such definitions, such that for any new empty `.ts` files in any new clean project, I will be able to type `Foo` and then get all the autocompletion suggestions. However, I haven't been able to find a good guide on how to get started. A pointer to a sample extension that does similar stuff would be good enough (I am new to writing VSCode extensions)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out ? I have exactly the same requirement now.